# How do I deliver 2 css with rails without actually applying them

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm trying to implement dark mode for my web app

1. i have `theme.scss` and `theme-dark.scss`
2. i added to initializer as following:
   `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w[theme.scss theme-dark.scss]`
3. i have my application.html.erb included `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'theme', media: 'all' %>` and `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'theme-dark', media: 'all' %>`
4. I have the following JS:

```
const insertStylesheet = ({ isRTL, isDark }, cb) => {
  const link = document.createElement('link');
  link.href = `/assets/theme${isDark ? '-dark' : ''}.scss`;
  link.type = 'text/css';
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.className = 'theme-stylesheet';

  link.onload = cb;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
  document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('dir', isRTL ? 'rtl' : 'ltr');
};

export default ({ isRTL, isDark }, cb) => {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('theme-stylesheet')).forEach(link => link.remove());
  insertStylesheet({ isRTL, isDark }, cb);
};
```

Now the issue is: using `<%= stylesheet_link_tag %>` would actually apply both stylesheets, so one overrides the other. but not specifying those, then my javascript wont be able to load these css files on the client to toggle.

So basically i want to deliver these css files to the client but not apply them to my html. thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the theme.scss and theme-dark.scss differently, so that they can happily co-exist on a page without conflict, for example:

```css
/* theme.scss */
body:not(.dark) {
  .container {
    background-color: #red;
  }
}

/*theme-dark.scss */
body.dark {
  .container {
    background-color: #blue;
  }
}
```

Then you switch themes by adding/removing the `.dark` class from the body element.

Comment: these files came from a bootstrap theme so it's much easier for me to keep them separate